# tricky union query using ruby on rails/active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I have

```
a = Profile.last
a.mailbox.inbox
a.mailbox.sentbox
active_conversations = [IDS OF ACTIVE CONVERSATIONS]

a.mailbox.inbox & active_conversations
```

returns part of what I need

I want

(a.mailbox.inbox & active_conversations) AND a.mailbox.sentbox

but I need it as SQL, so that I can order it efficiently.  I want to order it by ('updated_at')

I have tried joins and other things but they don't work. The classes of (a.mailbox.inboxa and the sentbox are

```
ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Conversation
```

but

```
(a.mailbox.inbox & active_conversations)
```

is an array

## edit

Something as simple as a.mailbox.inbox JOINS SOMEHOW a.mailbox.sentbox I should be able to work with, but I also can't seem to figure out.

Comment: Can you provide your associations as described in your models?

Comment: I am using mailboxer @Vapire https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/wiki if this isnt' enough info can you give me more detailed instructions on how to give you the information that you want

Comment: Do you want your desired result to be only ONE result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
(a.mailbox.inbox & active_conversations)
```

you should be able to do

```
a.mailbox.inbux.where('conversations.id IN (?)', active_conversations)
```

I believe the `Conversation` class (and its underlying `conversations` table) should be right according to the mailboxer code.

However this gives you an `ActiveRelation` object instead of an array. You can transform this to pure SQL using `to_sql`. So I think something like this should work:

```
# get the SQL of both statements
inbox_sql = a.mailbox.inbux.where('conversations.id IN (?)', active_conversations).to_sql
sentbox_sql = a.mailbox.sentbox.to_sql

# use both statements in a UNION SQL statement issued on the Conversation class
Conversation.from("#{inbox_sql} UNION #{sentbox_sql} ORDER BY id AS conversations")
```

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right! one interesting thing to note is that rails was ordering by id automatically and ruining the query, so the only thing I changed to make it work was added reorder -- so a.mailbox.sentbox.reorder('').to_sql -- also I should add that is is returning an array of hashes, and I don't know how to get the hash to behave properly.  I am figuring that our rn.